# Manjaro GNOMEでBluetoothイヤホン(AirPods)を接続しても強制的に切断されてしまう問題

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez, gnome

先日京都のアップルストアでAirPodsを購入しました。HUAWEI P20 liteでは問題なく動作しましたが、Manjaroでは認識してくれませんでした。

#### やってみたこと

まず`bluetoothctl`でスキャンをかけ、該当デバイスを検出後、

```
pair 00:00:00:00:00
trust 00:00:00:00:00:00
connect 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

を実行し、接続できたかと思いきや、GNOMEのBluetooth管理画面を見ると、何故か「切断」されていました(画像参照)。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

なぜこのような現象が起こっているのでしょうか？そして解決策は？英語は余り得意ではありませんが、英語記事を探しても解決には至らなかったので質問させていただきました。

Comment: 参考: [Pairing Apple Airpods as Headset - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/922860)

Comment: `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`の値を`ControllerMode = bredr`にしても`ControllerMode = dual`にしても駄目でした(Bluetoothは再起動済み)